# Logic network with NAND gates

Tags: logic-gates

I did a logic network  with only NAND gates to function below:

[image]

and my logic newtork

[image]

Is it correct?

Comment: Try marking each in-between output with the logical output to see if you have made an error i.e. break the problem down to smaller units. I can see an error but unless you start to analyse in sections you won't see that error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think my problem is with x2 output and I'm not sure about this one inverter, I think I have to delete it and change also for nand. It will be ok?

Comment: Did you not understand my 1st comment and advice?

Comment: You need to show a bit more effort here. Take the Boolean equation and simplify it. From there it will be easier to spot any mistakes by doing the steps Andy suggests.

Comment: Unfortunately this function has been simplified. I can use only De Morgan laws to solve this. I've split this function for small steps and I did new circuit, I've uploaded it in Update.

Comment: I think you should show the symbols of the inputs.

Comment: @NAND I've updated

Comment: You have 6 NANDs in circuit = 6 NANDs in equation.  A good start.  But you have \$\bar X_1\$ in equation, but not in circuit, so you are not correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your circuit simplifies to the equation Y = ~(~X1*X2)

[image]

While your equation seems to simplify to Y = ~(X1*X2*X3)

How I went about simplifying was to move the inversion to the Y side for the whole equation, to simplify the right hand side,

This leaves only getting a "1" when X1 = 0, X2 = 0 and the mess on the right, to get a 1 out of this immediately the second X2 can only be 0 and the second X1 can only be a 0 to have an output, meaning the only valid state for X3 is 0 to multiply to a change on the output.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I can't simplify it more because I can use only De Morgan laws to solve this.

Comment: I think if we simplified the equation, it will **NOT** be   Y = ~(X1*X2*X3), will it?

Answer (score 2):

First we should divide our problems to smaller parts.

We should begin from a symbol which has a lot of lines over it, in this case it's \$\overline{X_1}\$, but in the schematic there is no \$\overline{X_1}\$ found so it's first error.

Then we draw(track)  \$\overline{\overline{X_1}X_3}\$, then we draw(track) \$\overline{X_2}\$ and so on to reach our function \$Y\$

Using these steps will make you analyze the problem and discover errors faster!.

I think schematic should be like that:

[image]

Here is the schematic after editing it.

[image]

But I think you'd better simplify the boolean equation algebraically then try to draw our schematic. If we simplify it we will get
$$
Y=X_1+\overline{X_2}\,\overline{X_3}
$$